# Python - Receive muliple files

Tags: python, file, sockets, server, client

I'm learning socket programming and Python and I need to create a server that accepts several files from a client.
when I receive the one of the files I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//D'
```

I do not understand why!
Thanks for your help!

client.py

```
for files in directory:
        try:
            print files
            filename = files
            size = len(filename)
            size = bin(size)[2:].zfill(16) 
            s.send(size)
            s.send(filename)

            filename = os.path.join(path,filename)
            filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
            filesize = bin(filesize)[2:].zfill(32) #
            s.send(filesize)

            file_to_send = open(filename, 'rb')

            l = file_to_send.read()
            s.sendall(l)
            file_to_send.close()
            print 'File Sent'
        except socket.error, e:
            print "Error sending data: %s" % e
```

server.py

```
while True:
       size = clientsocket.recv(16)
       if not size:
           break
       size = int(size)
       filename = clientsocket.recv(size)
       filesize = clientsocket.recv(32)
       filesize = int(filesize,2)
       file_to_write = open("/home/giorgio/Scrivania/SERVER/Download/"+'new_'+filename, 'wb')
       num_files += 1
       chunksize = 1024
       while filesize > 0:
           if filesize < chunksize:
               chunksize = filesize
           data = clientsocket.recv(chunksize)
           file_to_write.write(data)
           filesize -= len(data)

       file_to_write.close()
       print 'File received successfully'


serversock.close()
```

Comment: filesize = int(filesize,2) why do you need this ?

Comment: Proximate cause: Line 5: In server `size = int(size)` should be `size = int(size, 2)`

Comment: Secondary: Q: If you call `recv(16)` how many bytes will you get back(). A: *not* necessarily 16, could be any number from 1 to 16 (or 0 if peer dies). TCP *does not guarantee to preserve message boundaries*.

Comment: Tertiary: Ditto with `send(buffer_of_len_X)`: does not guarantee that X bytes will be sent. Use `sendall`

Comment: @GilHamilton How can i simulate a "recvall()"? Sometimes this problem appears again. How can i be sure to receive the correct number of bytes?

Comment: You just need a while loop that calls `recv` with the remaining expected bytes until all expected bytes are received. `data = b""; while expected_bytes > 0:; tmp_buf = s.recv(expected_bytes); data += tmp_buf; expected_bytes -= len(tmp_buf)` (Substitute newline for semicolon and indent last three lines.)

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
       size = clientsocket.recv(16)
       if not size:
           break
       size = int(size)
       filename = clientsocket.recv(size)
       filesize = clientsocket.recv(32)
       #filesize = int(filesize,2) #This is not required and this is causing the error so remove it.
       file_to_write = open("/home/giorgio/Scrivania/SERVER/Download/"+'new_'+filename, 'wb')
       num_files += 1
       chunksize = 1024
       while filesize !="": #update to empty string comparison 
           if filesize < chunksize:
               chunksize = filesize
           data = clientsocket.recv(chunksize)
           file_to_write.write(data)
           filesize = len(data)

       file_to_write.close()
       print 'File received successfully'


serversock.close()
```

i have added comments for you to see the possible fixes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this does not work . I have this error :
filesize -= len(data)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: That was a typo it is fixed , sorry for that

Comment: @zatip was there any other issue why have u reopened the question again?

Comment: yep... seemed to have solved with the comments above .. but trying the scripts with two different PCs in the same network the same problem was repeated. With chunksize = 1024 it works with two PCs, with 4096 no, while running the scripts on my pc with 4096 works .. I think it's random

Comment: i believe it can be due to socket timeout maybe otherwise i dont see anything wrong with the answer

Comment: socket timeout?

Comment: Yes .Please read it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371096/how-to-use-python-socket-settimeout-properly and try it me know if it works for you

Comment: sorry for the huge delay. I'm very sorry. Thanks for help.. It was a problem of a variable that creates confusion in the code.

Comment: Cab you accept the answer so that others can refer to it